# Is it possible to hide a facebook app from being displayed in search engine results?

Tags: facebook, search-engine, facebook-apps

I have a facebook app (having the link: apps.facebook.com/XXX) that is now in sandbox and not available for public. Is there a way to prevent the search engine from indexing it and from showing it in search results.

In case there is no way to do that while the application is not deleted, I wanted to make sure that deleting the app on Facebook will for sure remove it from search engine results, since there is no way to restoring the Facebook app.

Thanks

Comment: I doubt that search engines can see your app if you use a robots.txt

Comment: I am not familiar with developing app on Facebook, I am just finding a way to hide it from search results, and didn't though about adding robots.txt to the Facebook app. So is it really possible to add robots.txt to a Facebook app ?

Comment: A "Facebook app" is basically a website which you host somewhere... So yes, you can use a robots.txt Why shouldn't you?